# Magento 2 catalog_product_get_final_price event not working for configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, event-observer

I have to set the product price to a custom value depends up on the customer. So I have written an event `catalog_product_get_final_price` and in the observer I have set the custom price for the product. But this is working only for "Simple Product" (visibility both). When I view the configurable product nothing is happened. Even I have write a `die()` in the observer and it is working when I view the Simple product but not for the configurable product. That means when I view the configurable product, the event is not triggering.

How can I set the simple product's price to a custom value using event? I need this for the "listing" and "view page"

Comment: Show your observer code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

First, you ***should tried your event on a default magento Instance***.

If it  ***will work then there might be some other  module*** that have overridden final price using `plugin`, or `event`.

if ***it won't work  on default magento*** then there ***`probanly are some issues in your observer code.`***

**Observer.code should like this:**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendorname]\[Modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class ProcesschangeFinalPriceObserver implements ObserverInterface
{


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $pId = $product->getId();
        $storeId = $product->getStoreId();
        $finalPrice = 100;
        $product->setPrice($finalPrice);
        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice); // set final price here 
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done as mention but it is not working

Comment: It is working fine for simple product not for configurable products

Comment: @zedBlackbeard That is because configurable products have their own Price class: `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Price` which does not issue a `catalog_product_get_final_price` event.